# Is there a shortcut to merge import statements

Tags: pycharm

I have the following import statements in a python file.

```
from a import b
from a import c
```

Now, i would like this to be merged into a single line like:

```
from a import b, c
```

I tried the Organise imports short cut from Pycharm: Ctrl+Shift+O. But, that did not do what i described above.

Is there any other short cut available to do this in Pycharm? just curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Python`

[image: pycharm merge imports]

Now in the imports tab of Python Code Style, check the box saying `Join "from" imports with the same source` as shown in the above screenshot,

now whenever you run **`Optimize imports`** by running  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or `code > Optimize imports`, the import statements will be optimized and arranged according to [Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: That's the answer i was looking for. Thanks a lot.